# LINQ to SQL Update not Updating

Tags: linq-to-sql, changeset

Simple LINQ update is not working. I make chages, but GetChangeSet returns 0 updates.

```
public bool Update(CompanyEmployee Employee)
{
    if (!isValid(Employee)) return false;
    var dc = new ERICustomersDataContext();
    var e = dc.CompanyEmployees.Single(c => c.Id == Employee.Id);
    if (e == null)
    {
        _ErrorMessage = "Not found";
        return false;
    }

    e.LastName = Employee.LastName;
    e.FirstName = Employee.FirstName;
    e.EmployeeNumber = Employee.EmployeeNumber;
    e.BusinessUnitId = Employee.BusinessUnitId;

    var ChangeSet = dc.GetChangeSet();
    if (ChangeSet.Updates.Count == 0)
    {
        _ErrorMessage = "Changeset is empty"; // <<<< THIS IS WHAT HAPPENS...
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        dc.SubmitChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two items: 1) are you sure the new values are different than the old values? 2) "dc.CompanyEmployees.Single(c => c.Id == Employee.Id)" will never return null so why check for it? It will throw if there is more or less than a single record. I think you want SingleOrDefault()?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem.  I had one table which refused to show changes or update.

I fixed it by deleting all the tables in my dbml file and then re-adding them.

Answer (score 0):

Two items:

1. are you sure the new values are different than the old values?
2. The following will never return null so why check for it? It will throw if there is more or less than a single record. I think you want SingleOrDefault()?

   dc.CompanyEmployees.Single(c => c.Id == Employee.Id)

Comment: Robinson - Yes, the values are different. I previously had the SingleOrDefault and changed it to Single in my testing, but that had no effect. I don't think the issue is apparent from the code. I suspect it may have something to do with security, but haven't been able to prove or disprove that yet.